# Is this integral operator a compact operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $D$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $$(T x)(t)=\int_{D}\frac{x(s)}{|t-s|^\alpha}{\rm d}s$$ Where $0<\alpha<n$. Then $T$ is a continuous operator on $C(D)$. Is it compact?

I've been thinking using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. For a bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$, it's easy to show $\{T x_n\}$ is uniformly bounded. But I failed to prove that they're equicontinuous, since
$\nabla |t-s|^{-\alpha}$ is not integrable when $\alpha \geq n-1$.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Then I would say that $T$ is not compact in the range $\alpha\in [n-1, n)$. A sequence $x_n$ of tent functions, all with the same height, but with shrinking base is equibounded, but your gradient observation SHOULD imply that $Tx_n$ is not equicontinuous, hence it is not compact. Just a rough idea

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition can help to prove equicontinuity in the case $\alpha\in[n-1, n).$

Comment: @dsh I still can't see how it could be applied to this question. Would you explain more specifically?

Comment: I do not have complete proof at hands(. Please elaborate your argument re. $\nabla |t-s|^{-\alpha}.$ This should be related to estimation $|f(x) - f(y)| <(\sup|\nabla f| )|x-y|$ which potentially can be replaced with weaker $|f(x) - f(y)| <C |x-y|^\beta, \beta < 1.$